# How to remove comments from Forked repository and Pull request on Owner's repository

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I have some comments, and pushed them to my **Forked** repository and pulled request them too to the owner's repository (someone else).

Now I want remove these comments and remove them form pull request too.

My repository:
[image]

Owner's repository:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run below command to merge them together:
`git reset --soft HEAD~14 &&
git commit`

And after this, push it like below, that `-f` stands for *force*:
`git push -f`

Result:
[image]
And
[image]

[Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/421467 ]

Answer (score 1):

- For first image - It looks like commit messages to me

If you do not want to see them just squash these commits.

- For 2nd Image - You can't delete the pull request but you can close pull request by [doing this](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request/) and if you do not to delete pull request the squash commit would be better idea.

Note that squashing a commit won't delete your commits but make multiple commits to one.

**Edit**
Try this command for squashing:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Result:

```
pick 01d1124 Adding license
pick 6340aaa Moving license into its own file
pick ebfd367 Jekyll has become self-aware.
pick 30e0ccb Changed the tagline in the binary, too.

# Rebase 60709da..30e0ccb onto 60709da
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Comment: 1- For squash, I changed `pick` word to `squash` word, but how to save and quit it?! I used triple `Android Studio Terminal` and `Windows command prompt git console` and `SourceTree Git shell`. 2- I closed pull request before, but the second image existed! Does the Owner should accept something? And another question, you're saying squashing the commits then send another pull request to owner, will clean the second image?

Comment: 1- Edited My answer for squashing a commit. 2 - what do you mean by  second image? did you mean "you can see your closed comment in the repo "? if this is the problem then it's normal. By looking at your answer " Just run below command to m............." it's look like your problem has been solved.